# Can we use one pageobject among different pages?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am working on one selenium project. My scenario is, I have multiple forms one after another. After filling them I have to click on the Next button. I have 4 pages with the next button and they have the same XPath. When I try to use the same web element for the next button it works once but when I try to use that same thing again on a different page It shows element intreactable error.

Comment: We need to see the full error stack trace, with your code trials

Comment: sorry sir, but I cant share stack trace or code it's against company policy. i hope you understand.

Comment: No, I don't understand that. Sharing error stacktrace won't do any harm to your company. Nobody can help you without seeing your code trials and exact errors. Happy coding !

Comment: I agree with @cruisepandey without stacktrace It would be difficult to analyze the solution for the error, meanwhile with your statement I can say the desired element `might` get overlayed on the next page just check and try to handle it.

Comment: There is not so much to go on. But it sounds like you need to find_elements by xpath and then click on [0], [1], [2], or [3] as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following to identify why you get the interactable error (it would help to give us the error at least as is found on the [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/allclasses-noframe.html))

- try to click using javascript executor,
- try to add webelements for each action you need to perform (so 4 webelements for each 'Next' button). If it works in this way maybe the webelement is not refreshed after you use it (maybe is a static field). Try also to work with Page Factory pattern.
  If nothing works, we should receive more information to be able to help.